# How to stop user from changing ID in url to access other records?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

using asp mvc 4.

When the user goes to a student record, the URL says:

```
http://studentTracker.org/Record/Student?studentId=380
```

Currently a user can change the studentId right there in the url and get that students record, unless it doesn't exist.  How can I either hide the query string  part of the url, or detect/validate at the controller if the user has changed the url?

Comment: I don't work with asp, but try storing the users id in a session variable or cookie and then compare the value of stored variable with the value of the `studentId`.  If they do not match then redirect the user somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you cannot stop a user from doing anything, really, especially something like changing an id in a URL. What you can do is ensure that if they do so, they get something like a 404 or 403, instead of the actual content.

The way to do that is to do object-level permissioning, which basically just means tying the object to the user(s) allowed to view/edit it in some way. Usually, this will done via foreign key to something like your "user" entity or something broader like a group or role.

For example, if the "Student 380" record is owned by `jdoe`, then you can prevent access to it by anyone but `jdoe` by first adding a foreign key to your "user" entity on your "student" entity. (Assuming Identity, since unspecified):

```
public class Student
{
    ...

    [ForeignKey("Owner")]
    public string OwnerId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Owner { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your action, instead of querying by just the id, you query by both the id in the URL *and* the id of the authenticated user:

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var student = db.Students.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == studentId && m.OwnerId == userId);
if (student == null)
{
    return new HttpNotFoundResult();
}
```

Now, if the user changes `studentId` but is not set as the "owner" of the student that matches, they'll get a 404.

Comment: So in this situation, the people that can view a student record are the counsellors, and they both have access to all student records.  So there is no security reason for them to not be able to do this, really it is fine as far as the business rules are concerned.  It just seems an awfully insecure why to get data in general.  I mean, cant the parameters be hidden in a header or something on a GET, so they are not visible in the URL?

Comment: No. That's not how HTTP works. The URI is a "unique resource identifier", Here, the `studentId` is what makes it unique and allows the server to return a particular student. It's also not "insecure". First, something like an id has no inherent value outside the database table, and if someone can see the database table, you have far more pressing concerns than exposing an id in a URL. As far as a user being able to manipulate it, that's always on the application to harden itself against such manipulations by doing something like what I've described here.

Comment: set studentid data type to guid by that it will be very hard to set parameter manually and get user information